# How do I construct the biadjacency matrix of a DAG?

Tags: matrix, graph-theory

For a [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), you can substitute the [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) with what is called its [biadjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Adjacency_matrix_of_a_bipartite_graph):

> The adjacency matrix A of a bipartite graph whose parts have r and s vertices has the form

```
    A =  O  B
         BT O
```

> where B is an r × s matrix and O is an all-zero matrix. Clearly, the matrix B uniquely represents the bipartite graphs, and it is commonly called its biadjacency matrix.

Now, a DAG is a bipartite graph, for example, you could [topologically sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ordering) it and have the sets U and V being nodes that are on an odd or even topological level, respectively.

This means, that for a DAG with n nodes, I only need a (n/2)<sup>2</sup> matrix (on average) instead of a n<sup>2</sup> matrix. Problem is, I don't know how to construct it. Any hints?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you can't construct a biadjacency matrix for a DAG, because not every DAG is a bipartite graph.

Here is a simple example: consider a directed graph with 3 vertices, and denote them as A, B and C. The edges connect A to B, B to C and A to C. The graph is clearly a DAG, since it is directed and there are no cycles (A->B->C<-A isn't a cycle). However, the graph is not bipartite: there is no way to divide A, B and C to two disjoint sets, where there are no edges between vertices in the same set.

The conclusion is that there graphes which are DAGs but not bipartite, so not every DAG is bipartite.

Note that the fact that you can topologically sort a DAG and divide the vertices to two disjoint sets, does not mean there are no edges between vertices of the same set.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to hear - but certainly true. :-) Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the biadjacency matrix B for the A matrix can only be constructed when the graph is undirected.

Based on the example from Wikipedia:

[image]

The adjacency matrices for this DAG should be:

```
Blue -> Red
B = 1 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0
    0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 1

Red -> Blue
C = 0 1 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0
    0 0 1 1 1
    0 0 0 0 0
```

As you can see C is not the transpose of B. It doesn't appear possible to create an A matrix as described. However, you could create an A matrix like this:

```
A = 0 B
    C 0
```

This would require 2 * (n/2)^2 space which is still better than n^2.

To construct the B and C matrices you just need to loop over each node in U and V (respectively) to determine the outbound edges.

Comment: For my given question, because I was mistaken on DAGs being bipartite, Oz's answer is probably slightly more correct, so I accepted his one. For practical purposes, though, yours was very helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create the biadjacency matrix of the given adjacency matrix, if it is bipatite (only bipatite graphs have biadjacency matrix.) If given graph is not bipatite, GetBiadjacencyMatrix() method returns null.

[Graph of the provided sample including its biadjacency matrix http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?10e9b6a746.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?10e9b6a746.jpg)

Can't see the image? [Click here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?10e9b6a746.jpg)

```
public class Matrix
{
    private void Usage()
    {
        int[,] AdjacencyMatrix = new int[,] { 
                                        {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                        {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                        {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                        {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
                                       };

        int[,] BiadjacencyMatrix = GetBiadjacencyMatrix(AdjacencyMatrix);
    }

    public static int[,] GetBiadjacencyMatrix(int[,] adjacencyMatrix)
    {
        int NodeCount = adjacencyMatrix.GetLength(0);

        NodeInfo[] Nodes = new NodeInfo[NodeCount];
        for (int c = NodeCount - 1; c >= 0; c--)
            Nodes[c] = new NodeInfo(c);

        if (ColorNode(adjacencyMatrix, Nodes, 0, 1, -1) != NodeCount)
            return null; // Given graph is not bipatite.

        int Part1Count = 0, Part2Count = 0;
        foreach (NodeInfo Node in Nodes)
            Node.IndexInPart = Node.PartID == 1 ? Part1Count++ : Part2Count++;

        int[,] ToReturn = new int[Part1Count, Part2Count];
        foreach (NodeInfo NodeInPart1 in Nodes)
            if (NodeInPart1.PartID == 1)
                foreach (NodeInfo NodeInPart2 in Nodes)
                    if (NodeInPart2.PartID == 2)
                        ToReturn[NodeInPart1.IndexInPart, NodeInPart2.IndexInPart]
                            = adjacencyMatrix[NodeInPart1.IndexInGraph, NodeInPart2.IndexInGraph];

        return ToReturn;
    }

    private static int ColorNode(int[,] adjacencyMatrix, NodeInfo[] nodes, int currentNode, int currentPart, int parentNode)
    {
        if (nodes[currentNode].PartID != -1) 
            return nodes[currentNode].PartID != currentPart ? -1 : 0;
        int ToReturn = 1;
        nodes[currentNode].PartID = currentPart;
        for (int c = nodes.Length - 1; c >= 0; c--)
            if (adjacencyMatrix[currentNode, c] != 0 && c != parentNode)
            {
                int More = ColorNode(adjacencyMatrix, nodes, c, currentPart == 1 ? 2 : 1, currentNode);
                if (More == -1) return -1;
                ToReturn += More;
            }
        return ToReturn;
    }
}


public class NodeInfo
{
    private int _IndexInGraph;
    private int _PartID;
    private int _IndexInPart;
    private bool _IsVisited;

    public NodeInfo(int indexInGraph)
    {
        _IndexInGraph = indexInGraph;
        _PartID = -1;
        _IndexInPart = -1;
        _IsVisited = false;
    }

    public int IndexInGraph
    {
        get { return _IndexInGraph; }
        set { _IndexInGraph = value; }
    }

    public int PartID
    {
        get { return _PartID; }
        set { _PartID = value; }
    }

    public int IndexInPart
    {
        get { return _IndexInPart; }
        set { _IndexInPart = value; }
    }

    public bool IsVisited
    {
        get { return _IsVisited; }
        set { _IsVisited = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the stated symmetry of your biadjacency matrix A, *and* your intention to use topological sorting to isolate a bipartite structure in the graph - point out that you are in fact referring to an **indirected**, acyclic, graph - i.e., a tree.
(A being symmetric explicitly says that if you have an edge from x to y, you must have an edge from y to x - hence, directedness becomes meaningless).

Assuming that is indeed your intention:

(1) As for any indirected graph, you can *immediately* settle for around 0.5*(n^2) (exactly: n(n-1)/2), by storing just the upper triangle of the adjacency matrix.

(2) Suppose you must store just B.

You must first identify disjoint subsets, say R & S, each having no internal edges. Topological sorting is a plausible option - in a tree, it amounts to picking a root and labeling vertices by being on even/odd levels above the root (in contrast with [common visualizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure), I prefer to think of a tree as actually growing *above* its root..). I understand from your question that you're comfortable with that, so I won't even give pseudo-code.

Next you need to re-label the vertices so that all R's vertices come first, and all S's vertices follow:

```
Allocate NewLabels(r + s);
CurRSize = 0;
CurSSize = 0;
for each (TreeLevel)
    if #CurLevel is even  // append to R vertices
       NewLabels(CurRSize : CurRsize + CurLevelSize - 1) = CurLevelVertexNums;
       CurRSize += CurLevelSize;
    else // append to S vertices
       NewLabels(r+s - (CurSSize+CurLevelSize) : r+s - (CurSSize + 1) = CurLevelVertexNums;
       CurSSize += CurLevelSize;
```

(Some optimizations immediately come to mind, but they're not important here).

Then, you can serially scan the graph edges, and store them as entries into the r x s matrix B, indexed by the *new* vertex labels:

```
Allocate B(r,s);
Zero(B);
for each (edge = x<-->y)
   i = NewLabels(x);
   j = NewLabels(y) - r; // must adjust, to index just B
   B(i,j) = 1;
```

HTH.